# Quickest way to scan a SQL Server table's column for 2 different values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, select, indexing

I have a table that has 10 columns. The first, the primary key, is a sequence int named "key". Another is named "status". One named "test_reference", and one named "warehouse", and one named "enabled" (a flag). The other columns can be ignored.

I need to scan the whole table and get a result set of all the rows in the table that have a "status" of either "6" or "7", and "enabled" be 1 (enabled). The statuses in "status" only range from 0-7 (integer values only).

This result set will need to be determined often (every 5 min), and on potentially 200k+ records. I'm sure there's a faster way than:

```
[select warehouse,
        test_reference
   from lgvftchinv
  where status in (8, 9)
    and enabled = 1]
```

I've created an index on (status,enabled). But if there is a much better solution out there, please help me!

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Add a persisted computed [bit] column MyFlag that will be 1 if status is 8 or 9 and enabled=1, otherwise set it 0, create an index on it and then make queries "...where MyFlag=1". By this, comparisons will be done before you need them. Should work faster. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Would it help the "persisted computation" to have an index on "status" at all? Or in this case, should I only put an index on MyFlag? Thank you for the suggestion by the way, I can't way to try it.

Comment: @user1776193 If you used my way then you'd only need an index on MyFlag. Btw, can't you test my solution at the moment or you cannot use it at all?

Comment: I think Jim meant that the "status" field does not need an index. With the result of the formula being persisted, the query doesn't need to look at the components of the formula.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a Filtered Index which would store only the rows that matched the subset you are looking for.  And assuming that the two columns you are selecting in your example are the only two you really want, you can also add an INCLUDE clause to make this a covering index (so you don't even need to go back to the table to get those values). Filtered Indexes were introduced in SQL Server 2008, btw.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_lgvftchinv_status_enabled
    ON lgvftchinv ( [status], [enabled] ) 
    INCLUDE ( warehouse, test_reference )
    WHERE [status] IN (8, 9)
        AND [enabled] = 1
```